# get a variable from a file in the sources section

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How can I get a variable from a file in the "sources" section of a link with selenium?

For example: How can I get the variable "var real" in the inspect -> Sources -> en/lol/team -> t1 file on the site "https://escorenews.com/en/lol/team/t1" ?

[variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wWuS.png)